# Creating debianpackage - the package is of bad quality

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I just created a debian package with

```
 dpkg-deb --build debtest
```

and when installing the package which containing a simple c-app a warning comes up

```
Lintian check results for /home/john/deb/debtest-1.0.deb:
E: debtest: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid makefile 1000/1000
E: debtest: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/ 1000/1000
E: debtest: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/local/ 1000/1000
E: debtest: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/local/bin/ 1000/1000
E: debtest: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/local/bin/hiapp3 1000/1000
```

is something in the controlfile wrong or missing?

```
Source: debtest
Section: unknown
Priority: optional
Maintainer: john <john-mg@debian.org>
Version: 1.0
Package: debtest
Architecture: amd64
Description: short descr
long descr .....
```

Comment: How are you installing the package? `dpkg -i`?

Comment: @StephenKitt - ubuntu software-center

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lintian checks the quality of your Debian package; generally speaking you can ignore its output for a simple package if you're not concerned about distributing the package. It's complaining about the ownership of the files in your package; they should be owned by `root`, not `john` (I'm guessing you're the user with uid 1000). Your control file looks fine (for a local package).

To fix this, so that the contents of the package are owned by `root`, run `dpkg-deb` with `fakeroot`:

```
fakeroot dpkg-deb --build debtest
```

If you're interested in learning about building Debian packages "the right way", I recommend reading [the Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/).

Comment: ok thanks - I read about a flag, -rfakeroot. May this flag solve the problem when creating the package? If it does - how could I use it together with **dpkg-deb --build debtest**  ?

Comment: That's a good idea; you'd run it as `fakeroot dpkg-deb --build debtest`, not `-rfakeroot` (which is a `dpkg-buildpackage` option).

Comment: I could first not upvote since i missed 2 reputations. When I accepted i got 15 so I could now upvote :)